# How to end git process with GitPython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have the error

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an
>   editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are
>   terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process may have
>   crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to
>   continue.

and I would like to get an alternative to  *rm -f .git/index.lock* by using gitPython, is it possible?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: The only solution is to manually remove the lockfile if you are certain that there is no other `git` process running at the same time.  You don't have to use `rm`; you can of course use Python's `os.remove`.

Comment: Hey how did you go about solving this.